# How to generate objects on scene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I'm using NSTimer to generate objects on my scene.
For example:

```
var enemyTimer = Timer()

enemyTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.8, target: self, selector:#selector(GameScene.enemyAppear),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

But I have some trouble. I need generate new objects with not time interval. I need to generate new nodes with some distance between them. For example 150 dots between objects. How Can I do this?
Sorry for my english...

Comment: You may want to use SKAction to spawn enemies because NSTimer is not paired with a game loop. So for example, if an user receives a phonecall, when he returns in a game, your screen will be full of enemies. Of course, you can listen for notifications and invalidate / restart NSTimer appropriately , but this is done automatically with SKActions (or update: method).

Answer (score 2):

Using a for loop and applying some math can solve this problem easily.

Let's say you want to generate 5 enemies, with 100 pixels between each, aligned in a horizontal line at y=0:

```
for i in 0..<5 { // repeat 5 times
    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "insert your texture for the enemy here") // create new enemy
    // here's the math part. When we generate the first enemy, i is 0, so it is at (0, 0). 
    // When it's time for the second enemy, i will be 1, so it will be placed at (100, 0)
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: 100 * i, y: 0)
    enemy.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.addChild(enemy)
}
```

You might also want to add your enemies into an array so you can retrieve them later.

Comment: Hello!
Thanks for the your answer. I want to create  new nodes  from out the screen. 
For example:
enemy.size = CGSize(x:160, y:80)
enemy.position = CGPoint (x:250,y:1200) (size of my scene = 768x1024)
and enemies will move to y:-100. And I need some distance between them. Can you help with that?
Thanks!

Comment: @NexusS. You don't need distance between off screen sprites! The user can't see them anyway. Just move each Sprite down every x seconds. This would make it seem like the sprites have spaces between them